# How to find elements in KML with CDATA using Groovy DOMBuilder?

Tags: groovy, kml, cdata

I am using Groovy 1.8.6 to parse KML files having CDATA in description element and return with parent (i.e. Placemark) element.
The KML looks like this:

```
    <Placemark>
    <description><![CDATA[
      ID=SVM10<br>
    ]]></description>
    </Placemark>
```

and input as the first argument into Groovy code looks like this:

```
    def reader = new FileReader(args[0])
    def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(reader)
    def content = doc.documentElement

    use (DOMCategory) {
      def point = content.Document.Placemark.findAll{ it.text().contains('SVM') }
      println point.size()
    }
```

But it shows 0 - that is no record was found.
How can I modify the code so it can find contents within CDATA brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why your code doesn't work, but you can use XPath to do same :

```
package groovyxml

import groovy.xml.DOMBuilder
import javax.xml.xpath.*

String source = """
<Placemark>
    <description>oo<![CDATA[
      ID=SVM10<br>
    ]]>aa</description>
    </Placemark>
    """

    def reader = new StringReader(source)
    def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(reader)
    def xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
    def point = xpath.evaluate( 
      "/Placemark/description[contains(text(), 'SVM')]", 
      doc, 
      XPathConstants.NODESET )
    println point.length
```

... print 1.